# Changing internal state of hash in Python

Tags: python, sha256

In a C program, I can change the internal state of the SHA256 algo as follows:

```
SHA256_CTX c;
SHA256_Init(&c);
for (i =0; i<64; i++)
    SHA256_Update(&c, "$", 1);

# 0x44332211 is just for example
c.h[0] = htole32(0x44332211);
c.h[1] = htole32(0x44332211);
c.h[2] = htole32(0x44332211);
c.h[3] = htole32(0x44332211);
c.h[4] = htole32(0x44332211);
c.h[5] = htole32(0x44332211);
c.h[6] = htole32(0x44332211);
c.h[7] = htole32(0x44332211);
```

Python provides `hashlib.sha256`. I want to ask if there is any way in which the internal state of sha256 algo can be updated in Python similar to what I did in C above ?

Comment: The hash objects created by `hashlib` (`type(m) == _hashlib.HASH`) are [implemented in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_hashopenssl.c), and `dir(m)` shows nothing more than its member functions. Verdict: not possible without dirty hacks (e.g. using `ctypes`).

Comment: In addition to what @meowgoesthedog said the SHA256_CTX struct is intended to be an opaque data type. Modifying the content of the structure is not supported and could result in the HCF instruction being executed.